# iOS 13 UIToolBar Style

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uitoolbar

I am trying to create a tool bar for the number pad I am using in swift, but am getting this warning with the following code:

`'blackTranslucent' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES instead`

I am not seeing any property of type `UIBarStyleBlack` with `UIToolBar`, how can I get rid of this warning?

```
let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
doneToolbar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `doneToolbar.isTranslucent = true`